# SQL Server - is "ALL" a special value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking at a table with records that has a field with either numeric values or

```
<ALL>
```

as values in the records. I'm thinking that the table creator put this value in to show that this field with an "all" should join with all records

But, it looks so much like a

```
<NULL>
```

I was wondering if I'm missing some special SQL function or operator where I could use this in a join. Otherwise, I think I'll have to use a case statement.

```
fieldCode       AccountCode       CategoryCode
MealsBreakfast  S141    ALL (the ALL value here also has the < and > characters around it)
MealsBreakfast  S143    153000
MealsBreakfast  S143    153050
```

Comment: No, the only "special" value SQL is aware of is NULL. Everything else is application-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the field contains numeric values and `'<ALL>'`, then the field is declared as a string.  There is no special "all" value in SQL.

This sounds like poor data design.  I have spent too many hours helping to debug queries where a supposed numeric value sometimes contains a special "string", causing a conversion failure on an unknown row and unknown column.

I would recommend either a user-defined type.  Or two columns, one being numeric with a `NULL` value and the second being a "type" of the value.